# Efficiently label each row in a large dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a file containing dates from June 2015 + 365 days. I am using this as a lookup table because there are custom business dates (only certain holidays are observed and there are some no-work dates because of internal reasons). Using the customer business date offsets was just so slow with 3.5 million records.

```
initial_date | day_1      | day_2      | day_3      | ... | day_365
2015-06-01     2015-06-02   2015-06-03   2015-06-04
2015-06-02     2015-06-03   2015-06-04   2015-06-05
```

The idea is to 'tag' each row in the data based on the number of (custom) business dates since specific entries. Is there a better way to do this?

For example, if a new entry happens on 2016-06-28 then this is labeled as `'initial_date'`. `day_1` is tomorrow, `day_2` is the next day, `day_3` is Friday, and `day_4` is next Monday.

My naive way of doing this is to create a loop which basically does this:

```
 df.day_1_label = np.where(df.date == df.day_1, 'Day 1', '')
 df.day_2_label = np.where(df.date == df.day_2, 'Day 2', '')

df.day_label = (df.day_1_label + df.day_2_label + ...).replace('', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

This would result in one label per row which I could then aggregate or plot. Eventually this would be used for forecasting. `initial_date + the subset of customers from previous dates = total customers`

Also, depending on what events happen, a subset of the customers would have a certain event occur in the future. I want to know on what business date from the initial_date this happens on, on average. So if we have 100 customers today, a certain percent will have an event next July 15th or whatever it might be.

Edit- pastebin with some sample data:

http://pastebin.com/ZuE1Q2KJ

So the output I am looking for is the day_label. This basically checks if the date == each date from day_0 - day_n. Is there a better way to fill that in? I am just trying to match the date of each row with a value in one of the day_ columns.

Comment: Could you maybe redo this to have a small toy dataset and code block of your solution in action?  Reproducing it would make it a lot easier to think about.

Comment: I added some example data on a pastebin link

Comment: @trench Do you have one fixed calendar (i.e. June 2015 + 365 days) you are using? And all rows in your data (`initial_date` to `day_20`) are contiguous subsets of this calendar? If so, then you probably need to know only `date` and `initial_date` to get `day_label`. I can write the code for you later.

Comment: I ended up creating a lookup table for this with a separate csv file. I then merge that file on the row date. I then have an np.where statement in a loop. If the row date equals the day 0 date then day 0, etc. This loop goes from 0 to 365 but it completes okay. If there is a more efficient way then that'd be cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be made more efficiently if your data looks as I think it looks.

Say you have a calendar of dates (June 2015 + 365 days) and a data frame as for example:

```
cal = ['2015-06-01', '2015-06-02', '2015-06-03', '2015-06-04', '2015-06-08',
       '2015-06-09']

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2015-06-04', '2015-06-09', '2015-06-09'],
                   'initial_date': ['2015-06-02', '2015-06-02', '2015-06-01']})
```

Keeping dates in numpy.datetime types is more efficient, so I convert:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(np.datetime64)
df['initial_date'] = df['initial_date'].astype(np.datetime64)
```

Now, let's turn `cal` into a fast lookup table:

```
# converting types:
cal = np.asarray(cal, dtype=np.datetime64)

# lookup series
s_cal = pd.Series(range(len(cal)), index=cal)

# a convenience lookup function
def lookup(dates):
    return s_cal[dates].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

The above `lookup` returns a series with a `RangeIndex`, which may be different from the index of `df` (this causes problems when assigning the result to a column). So it's probably better to rewrite this lookup so that it returns a plain numpy array:

```
def lookup2(dates):
    return s_cal[dates].values
```

It's possible to set the correct index in `lookup` (taken from the input `dates`). But such a solution would be less flexible (would require that the input be a `Series`) or unnecessarily complicated.

---

The series:

```
s_cal
Out[220]: 
2015-06-01    0
2015-06-02    1
2015-06-03    2
2015-06-04    3
2015-06-08    4
2015-06-09    5
dtype: int64
```

and how it works:

```
lookup(df.date)
Out[221]: 
0    3
1    5
2    5
dtype: int64

lookup2(df.date)
Out[36]: array([3, 5, 5])
```

The rest is straightforward. This adds a column of integers (day differences) to the data frame:

```
df['day_label'] = lookup2(df.date) - lookup2(df.initial_date)
```

and if you want to convert it to labels:

```
df['day_label'] = 'day ' + df['day_label'].astype(str) 

df
Out[225]: 
        date initial_date day_label
0 2015-06-04   2015-06-02     day 2
1 2015-06-09   2015-06-02     day 4
2 2015-06-09   2015-06-01     day 5
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Awesome let me try this out later and if it works ill click the check box

Comment: This worked and it was a lot faster and I do not need to manage 1) A separate file, and 2) a bunch of for loops. Great stuff

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Is there any reason why assigning these values to a column seems to scramble them or produce incorrect results? lookup(df.date) - lookup(df.initial_date) works perfectly fine, but if I say df['col'] = lookup(df.date) - lookup(df.initial_date) then the results are different. It could be a stupid mistake I am making but I am frustrated now.

Comment: @trench This probably happens because `df` and the output of `lookup` have different indexes. Sorry, I overlooked it earlier. Please, see the updated `lookup2`. Hope this would solve the problem.

Comment: FYI this has been working well. I have to do this fairly often and the data is continually growing (5.2 mil rows right now) so the speed increase is very noticeable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @trench Good to hear it works as expected. Thanks for the feedback.